# run mrjob on Amazon EMR, t2.micro not supported

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr, mrjob

I tried to run a mrjob script on Amazon EMR. It worked well when I used instance c1.medium, however, it had an error when I changed instnace to t2.micro. The full error message was shown below.

> C:\Users\Administrator\MyIpython>python word_count.py -r emr 111.txt
>   using configs in C:\Users\Administrator.mrjob.conf creating new
>   scratch bucket mrjob-875a948553aab9e8 using
>   s3://mrjob-875a948553aab9e8/tmp/ as our scratch dir on S3 creating tmp
>   directory c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\word_count.Administr
>   ator.20150731.013007.592000 writing master bootstrap script to
>   c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\word_cou
>   nt.Administrator.20150731.013007.592000\b.py
>
> PLEASE NOTE: Starting in mrjob v0.5.0, protocols will be strict by
>   default. It's  recommended you run your job with --strict-protocols or
>   set up mrjob.conf as de scribed at
>   https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/whats-new.html#ready-for-strict-protoc
>   ols
>
> creating S3 bucket 'mrjob-875a948553aab9e8' to use as scratch space
>   Copying non-input files into
>   s3://mrjob-875a948553aab9e8/tmp/word_count.Administ
>   rator.20150731.013007.592000/files/ Waiting 5.0s for S3 eventual
>   consistency Creating Elastic MapReduce job flow Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "word_count.py", line 16, in 
>       MRWordFrequencyCount.run()   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\job.py", line 461, in run
>       mr_job.execute()   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\job.py", line 479, in execute
>       super(MRJob, self).execute()   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\launch.py", line 153, in
>   execute
>       self.run_job()   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\launch.py", line 216, in
>   run_job
>       runner.run()   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\runner.py", line 470, in run
>       self._run()   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\emr.py", line 881, in
>   _run
>       self._launch()   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\emr.py", line 886, in
>   _launch
>       self._launch_emr_job()   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\emr.py", line 1593, in 
>   _launch_emr_job
>       persistent=False)   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\emr.py", line 1327, in 
>   _create_job_flow
>       self._job_name, self._opts['s3_log_uri'], **args)   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\retry.py", line
>   149, i n call_and_maybe_retry
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\retry.py", line 71, in 
>   call_and_maybe_retry
>       result = getattr(alternative, name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\emr\connection.py",
>   lin e 581, in run_jobflow
>       'RunJobFlow', params, RunJobFlowResponse, verb='POST')   File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line
>   12 08, in get_object
>       raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body) boto.exception.EmrResponseError: EmrResponseError: 400 Bad Request
>   
>   
>       Sender
>       `ValidationError`
>       Instance type 't2.micro' is not supported      c3ee1107-3723-11e5-8d8e-f1011298229d

This is my config file detail

```
runners:
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxx
    aws_secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    aws_region: us-east-1
    ec2_key_pair: EMR
    ec2_key_pair_file: C:\Users\Administrator\EMR.pem
    ssh_tunnel_to_job_tracker: false
    ec2_instance_type: t2.micro
    num_ec2_instances: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMR doesn't support the `t2` instance type. If you're worried about money, spot instances are a very cost-effective option: right now `m1.xlarge` is less than $0.05 per hour, and `m1.medium` is $0.01 per hour (cheaper than `t2.micro` anyway) Supported types are the following (screenshot from the EMR webapp console:

[image]

[image]